# Game in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I've been trying to make a game in Haskell, but i've encountered some problems on the way.
First here's an output of what all this should look like:

```
Main> symbol 3  
1: *  
2: **  
3: ***  

First Player  
Line: 3  
Symbols: 2  

1: *  
2: **  
3: *  

Second Player  
Line: 1  
Symbols: 1  

1:  
2: **    
3: *  

First Player   
Line: 3  
Symbol: 1  

1:  
2: **  
3:  

Second Player   
Line: 2  
Symbols: 2  

Second Player Wins!
```

Then, the functions:

```
import System.IO    
import Data.List  

--The Game Data Structure  

data Player = Player Bool   
instance Show Player where 
show ( Player False ) = " First "  
show ( Player True ) = " Second "  
First : : Player  
First = Player False  
next : : Player −> Player  
next ( Player b ) = Player ( not b )  

type Symbol = Int  
type Line = Int  

-- The Function to update the game each time something happens  

updateGame :: [ Symbol ] −> Line −> Symbol −>  [ Symbol ]  
updateGame game line symbol = take ( line − 1) game ++  
game !! (line − 1) − symbol : drop line game  

getLine : : [ Symbol ] −> IO Line  
getLine game = getNumber "Line: "  
(\n −> n >= 1 && n <= length game &&  
game !! (n − 1) /= 0)  

getSymbols : : [ Symbol ] −> Line −> IO Symbol  
getSymbols game line = getNumber "Symbols: "  
(\n−> n> 0 && n<=game !! (line−1))  

endOfGame : : [ Symbol ] −> Bool   
endOfGame game = sum gane == 0   

symbol :: Int −> IO ()  
symbol n = do  
winner <− play [1..n] first  
putStrLn $ show winner ++ " Player Won! "
```

All the functions i just wrote i think are 100% correct, but there are three of them i'm struggling with:

```
getNumber :: String −> (Int −> Bool) −> IO Int  
getNumber = do  
    num <- fmap read getLine  
    if num > 0 || num <= (y :: Line)   
    then return (Just num)  
    else putStrln "Invalid Number!" >> return Nothing
```

This one i'm not sure about the syntax, because, despite the fact that it kind of makes sense to me (the logic of the code, per say), i'm not sure it does what it's supposed to do.

```
showGame :: [Symbol] −> IO ()    
play :: [Symbol] −> Player −> IO Player
```

Now i know i'm supposed to write some code to illustrate my attempts towards the right solution, but with this two functions i'm totally clueless. I mean, i know what they should do, but i guess my extensive background of java keeps making my life miserable every time i try something new in Haskell... Despite that, the first function (showGame) should print out a game "board", like the one i showed before, but like the following function i don't know how can i do the line numbers and the symbols "increase" in Haskell, i mean, i'm so used to do for loops or while loops in java to deal with this situations, that i get stuck every time i have to "replicate" it in Haskell. The second one is the game itself. In java i would do a "do..while" loop and be done with it, but i have no idea how that works in Haskell.

It would be great if you guys could help me out, because i've put so much effort into this, asked so many people for help and tips, and that got me so close to the "end", that it would be a total waste of time to leave it just like that...

Comment: The functions in your first block are not 100% correct, the indentation is garbled. I suppose that happened when you paste the code here?

Comment: @leftaroundabout Oh sorry! Yes it happened when i pasted it in here!

Comment: You can fix it yourself: as you've seen you can edit your post (though the previous one was invalid, this question has nothing to do with type classes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
getNumber :: String −> (Int −> Bool) −> IO Int  
getNumber = do
```

This already can't be right: getNumber is a function of two arguments, but you accept none and try to go into the `IO` monad right away<sup>1</sup>. Just match on the arguments like you would in any other function! I suppose it should be

```
getNumber question requirement = do
```

where `question` would be a prompt. Next up,

```
   if num > 0 || num <= (y :: Line)
```

what is `y`? I think you shouldn't do any hard-coded comparison at all there, but *use the supplied predicate*!

```
   if requirement num
```

Further,

```
      then return $ Just num
      else putStrln "Invalid Number!" >> return Nothing
```

doesn't work because you *must* return an `Int`, there's no `Maybe` in the signture. Since you nevertheless can't accept any input, you'll probably need to implement a *loop* (i.e. recurse back in the fail-case). The result might be:

```
askForNumber :: String −> (Int −> Bool) −> IO Int  
askForNumber question requirement = do
   putStr question
   num <- fmap read getLine
   if requirement num
     then return num
     else do
        putStrLn "This does not meet the requirements! Please try again..."
        askForNumber question requirement
```

As for the other functions: `showGame` is evidently enough supposed to display those rows of `**` on screen. That's extremely easy: you renerate a list of `n` asterisks with `replicate n '*'`. Since a list of chars is a string, you can simply `putStrLn` it.

`play` will need to be an actual loop, i.e. recurse at the end while the `endOfGame symbolState` is false.

---

<sup>1</sup>In fact, functions form a monad as well so in principle it's possible to begin the definition thus... but that's definitely not what you're after here.

Comment: The last function is basically the "main" function, the one who puts everything "running", until the game ends

Comment: the y in the getNumber function, is basically because i want to say that the number inserted, can't be bigger than the max line numbers. For example, if we have 3 lines, the number inserted can't be bigger than 3

Comment: You shouldn't do an explicit check on some `y` if you have a generic predicate for this purpose!

Comment: So how can i do it ? If i wasn't clear at any point, please let me know... if i'm not supposed to use y, what should i use ? just Line ?

Comment: No, use the supplied predicate! `if requirement num`.

Comment: in the showGame function if i do replicate n , and n equals 3, it will only show one line, which is not what i want... how can i do a loop(if that's what i'm supposed to do)?

Comment: I'm sorry but i'm really not following on what you are saying, can you give me some sort of example ?

Comment: I could, but I won't. Read some [tutorial/books/etc.](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Learning_Haskell) for examples. Then try something and post it. — All right, I'll do the full corrected version of `getNumber`, but not `showGame` and `play`: you first...

Comment: ok far enough! i'll try it out and then i'll get back to you!

Comment: So for the showGame function, here's my attemp: 
showGame :: [Symbol] −> IO ()  
showGame xs = putStrln map replicate  '*' xs, i got confused, because this function takes a list i suppose, but it doesn't make sense at the same  time. i really could  use some help

Comment: Not bad. You just need to add parens so it's parsed correctly, and [combine the rows of asterisks](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=unlines).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41912/discussion-between-user3028943-and-leftaroundabout)

Comment: i don't see how the underlines function is going to help me, and the code i wrote refers just to one line doesn't it ? I mean, it would only print one line

Comment: Come on. You now got all the tools. If you don't get it, then play around with them in GHCi until you properly know what each is doing. If I just give you the solution to everything, you're not gonna understand any of it.

Answer (score -1):

For the showGame function, anyone can tell me why this isn't working ?

```
import System.IO  

type Symbol = Int  

showGame :: [Symbol] => IO ()  
showGame xs =   
    let x = mapM_ flip (replicate '*') xs  
    putStrLn x
```

The output should be:

```
1: *  
2: **  
3: ***
```

with

```
 [Symbol] = [1,2,3]
```

Comment: You should post amended questions either as edits to your original post or as completely new questions, but not as answers. And it probably doesn't work because (a) you need to `flip` `replicate` to get the right argument order, and (b) you never output the "1:" etc, and (3) the entire structure of the definition doesn't make sense. You're trying to pass `mapM_` as an argument to `putStrLn`.

Comment: @SebastianRedl i updated it! i was getting confused because replicate takes 2 "arguments", per say, and so does map, and because i wanted to print the whole thing, i figured it made sense to put everything inside putStrLn. As i can see from your comment, this is definitely not the right way to do it. any tips on how i can make it right ?